# Database stuck on restoring state when the restore stored procedure is call on .net but ok when running on SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that will backup a database and restore a new database base on the backup.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CloneBaseAQSDB]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@destDb NVARCHAR(50) AS
BEGIN


-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @backupPath nvarchar(400);
DECLARE @sourceDb nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @sourceDb_log nvarchar(50);

DECLARE @destMdf nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @destLdf nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @sqlServerDbFolder nvarchar(100);

SET @sourceDb = 'based_db'
SET @sourceDb_log = @sourceDb + '_log'


SET @backupPath = 'C:\MSSQL\Backup\' + @sourceDb + '.bak'   
SET @sqlServerDbFolder = 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\'

SET @destMdf = @sqlServerDbFolder + @destDb + '.mdf'
SET @destLdf = @sqlServerDbFolder + @destDb + '_log' + '.ldf'

BACKUP DATABASE @sourceDb TO DISK = @backupPath

RESTORE DATABASE @destDb FROM DISK = @backupPath
WITH REPLACE,
   MOVE @sourceDb     TO @destMdf,
   MOVE @sourceDb_log TO @destLdf   
END
```

When I try to run the stored procedure on SQL it will run successfully and the database is accessible.
It will have this result.

```
 Processed 4520 pages for database 'based_db', file 'based_db' on file 18.
 Processed 2 pages for database 'based_db', file 'based_db_log' on file 18.
 BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 4522 pages in 1.516 seconds (23.303 MB/sec).
 Processed 4520 pages for database 'AQS_NEW', file 'based_db' on file 1.
 Processed 2 pages for database 'AQS_NEW', file 'based_db_log' on file 1.
 RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 4522 pages in 44.801 seconds (0.788 MB/sec).
```

But when I tried to call the stored procedure on .net using sqlCommand. The command will finish executing but the database is getting stuck on restoring state.

```
    public void clonedBaseDatabase() {
        string connString = Common.setConnstring(Common.master_user, Common.master_pass, "master");
        string query = "CloneBaseAQSDB";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destDb", DB_NAME);
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.addErrorMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: I already tried to have a method that will check if the database is accessible or not before closing the connection because I think the problem is  .net is already closing the connection immediately before the restore script is finished.  But the database is still in restoring state even the connection is not closed.

Comment: It's better to [edit] the question to add more information.

Comment: According to your log output from SSMS the `RESTORE DATABASE` operation took 44 seconds. `SqlCommand` has a [default CommandTimeout of 30 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout). It's probably trying to cancel the operation when it times out.

Comment: Side note: `@destDb` should probably be `sysname` (alias for `nvarchar(128)`) and the other variables should probably be `nvarchar(255)`

Comment: yeah, the problem is in command time out. After adding command time out =0. It works.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). You also make MANY assumptions about the database - the logical names and the physical names. Beware!

Answer (score 0):

As per AlwaysLearning comment I just add

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

and it works!